# Init a 3 dimensional array with 2 dimensional arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

Sorry if this may seem like a stupid question.

I had this code:

```
char array1[2];
char array2[2];
char array3[2];

char *array[] = {
array1,
array2,
array3,
}
```

Now I changed array1,array2,array3 to be a 2 dimensional array:

```
char array1[2][2];
char array2[2][2];
char array3[2][2];
```

And I get the following error:
`error: cannot convert 'char (*)[2]' to 'char*' in initialization`

How can I init array with 2 dimensional array?

I also tried the following which didn't work:

```
char *array[2][2] = {
    array1,
    array2,
    array3,
    }

char array[][2][2] = {
    array1,
    array2,
    array3,
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 makes this easy:

```
char array1[2][2];
char array2[2][2];
char array3[2][2];


std::decay<decltype(array1)>::type array[] = {
  array1,
  array2,
  array3,
};
```

which is the equivalent of the (*unreadable in my opinion*) syntax

```
char (* array [])[2] = {
  array1,
  array2,
  array3,
};
```

The rules, as usual, are the same you can find in [every decent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list):

- Operator precedence
- Type decaying

Comment: add an asterik, it will work for you
char* array[][2][2] = {
    array1,
    array2,
    array3,
    }